# xcode : How do I make sure the deployment target of my binary is set at 3.0?

Tags: iphone, xcode, deployment, ios

How do I make sure the deployment target of my binary is set at 3.0? My base SDK is 4.0 because I'm using xcode 3.2.4 and this is the only SDK I can use. I thought it was possible to get the binary to target 3.0 using the settings in the Build properties but when I upload the binary to iTunes Connect it still says the minimum os is 4.0.[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is basically right however there is more than one target. When you go to the menu->project-> there are 3 target options, one of the is "active" target, I know it seems the same as changing the configuration, but it's not. Try changing also the "active" one, this should fix the problem.